# Do users even use tool tips?

Tags: website-design, tooltips

I was reading [this SO meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271811/1185053) and it got me wondering - does the average Web user know about tool tips and use them?

For me if I don't know what an icon does on a site, my default is to roll over it and see if it has a tool tip. But I am a Web developer.

Are tool tips just by Web developers for Web developers or does the average user actively know about and use them?

Comment: Ah yes. Exact duplicate! On mobile so didn't come up on search.